# How do I prevent files from being saved as .webarchive

Tags: macos, safari

Whenever I want to save files like `.csv` files that were open in a safari tab, it forces me to either name it as `.csv.webarchive` or `.webarchive`. Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer the question about Saving in Safari:

When you are about to save a page you are viewing in Safari, you will find a Select option in the saving dialogue, that will let you choose the format you want to save the page.

By default it will be set as Web Archive. But you can change it to Page Source, so it will save on the source of the page, which in the csv case, it will save the csv file.

Next time, Safari will remember your last choice.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here is another small tip, for downloading files like csv, pdf, mp3 etc, that are opened and viewable in a Safari tab/window and have been accessed directly through their urls (e.g. the url address in safari address bar is something like: www.example.com/mycsv.csv, or www.example.com/mymovie.mp4, and so on...)

1. Go and click inside the address bar, so it gets active.
2. Hold the ALT key down, and stroke once the ENTER key.

Safari will reload the current page, and immediately will start downloading the current file.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know I could do that :) Thanks

Comment: This is a great tip!  If this works for you, please mark it as answered for others.  Cheers!

Comment: @bjbk It does, but I would still prefer to disable it, if I can. I'm guessing I probably can't, in which case I'll wait for a few more hours and accept this as an answer.

Comment: I wonder if `option` + `Return` would work on the original link as well?  If so that may be the ticket!  *searching for a webpage to try it on*

Comment: @bjbk:: The Option + clicking on the original link will work.

Answer (score 2):

[Webarchive (Wikipedia link)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webarchive) is a attempt to save the complete web page itself including all CSS and JavaScript files associated with it, not merely the CSV data displayed on the page.

If the site you are browsing contains a *link* to the file you need, you may be able to download it with an Option+Click or right click **Download Linked File As...**

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but I don't always have the chance to do that. The case with the `.csv`s was that when I click on the link, an html dialogue appears first, and when I click ok, the new tab with the `.csv` opens.

Answer (score -3):

Just rename the file as .csv  It may leave some residual information you don't need but just delete it...simple.